# Create list items in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am working on cordova app .I want to create list items using jquery . here is my html code :

```
 <div class="body" id="list">
        <ul class="list list-messages" id="list">


        </ul>
      </div>
```

And this is my js code :

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".navbar-title").html(localStorage.getItem("Provider"));

        $.ajax({
            type: 'Get',
            url: 'http://41.128.183.109:9090/api/data/getalllocations',
            success: function (data) {

            for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {

$("#list").append('<li class="list-message" data-ix="list-item"><a class="w-clearfix w-inline-block" href="chat.html" data-load="1"><div class="w-clearfix column-left"><div class="image-message"><img src="images/128.jpg"></div></div><div class="column-right"><div class="message-title">James White</div><div class="message-text">Hey dude! We are waiting for you at the main station, we will meet you near to....</div></div></a></li>');

                }

            }
        });
        });
    </script>
```

Its not working . please advice

Comment: use `append` instead of `html()`

Comment: `innerHtml` is a javascript `property`. and it gives html value and you can set html value. But for pushing `html` you can use `append` of `jQuery
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should  [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)
 not [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

`Html()` replaces value and `append()` inserting value.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {

                $("#list").empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                    $("#list").append('<li class="list-message" data-ix="list-item"><a class="w-clearfix w-inline-block" href="chat.html" data-load="1"><div class="w-clearfix column-left"><div class="image-message"><img src="images/128.jpg"></div></div><div class="column-right"><div class="message-title">James White</div><div class="message-text">Hey dude! We are waiting for you at the main station, we will meet you near to....</div></div></a></li>');

                }    
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body" id="list">
        <ul class="list list-messages" id="list">


        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: `innerHtml` is a javascript `property`. and it gives html value and you can set html value. But for pushing `html` you can use `append` of `jQuery
`

Comment: yes checked. as you have make answer of other person but check to do `$("#list").empty();` before append. Ex. If your `ajax` return 0 data then you need to `.empty()` on success first. On html it should have zero `li` not `previous` `list items`

Comment: Thanks for making it answer.

Comment: i do this but it seems that it get data but it isn't appear . i dont know why

Answer (score 3):

You should use `.append()` instead of `.html()`

`.html()` is replacing the content of your div, `.append()` will add some content

```
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    $("#list").append('<li class="list-message" data-ix="list-item"><a class="w-clearfix w-inline-block" href="chat.html" data-load="1"><div class="w-clearfix column-left"><div class="image-message"><img src="images/128.jpg"></div></div><div class="column-right"><div class="message-title">James White</div><div class="message-text">Hey dude! We are waiting for you at the main station, we will meet you near to....</div></div></a></li>');
}
```

Comment: yes it solved but what is the different between html and innerhtml and append ? thank you

Comment: `.html()` is a jQuery method, it **sets** the HTML of your div ;

`.innerHTML` is a vanilla javascript **property**, you can set its value with `item.innerHTML = 'xxx'` ; 

`.append()` is a jQuery method, it will **add** some content to you div

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            $("#list").append('<li class="list-message" data-ix="list-item"><a class="w-clearfix w-inline-block" href="chat.html" data-load="1"><div class="w-clearfix column-left"><div class="image-message"><img src="images/128.jpg"></div></div><div class="column-right"><div class="message-title">James White</div><div class="message-text">Hey dude! We are waiting for you at the main station, we will meet you near to....</div></div></a></li>');

        }

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="body" id="list">
        <ul class="list list-messages" id="Ul1">
        </ul>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by delete "data-ix="list-item"
Now My Code is :
 $("#list").append('James WhiteHey dude! We are waiting for you at the main station, we will meet you near to....');
 I dont Know Why But it is running now .